# Why my cmd disapears? I use cin.ignore() but it has no effect! C++

Tags: c++

I'm testing my roulette classes but visual studio don't let me see the output since **cin.ignore()** does not work, and I have no idea what going on here,

can you explain why my cmd line window disapear and why **cin.ignore()** in this code never gets invoked?

Thank you so much!

```
#include "Bet.h"
#include "Table.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Roulette;


int main()
{
    cout << "Enter numbers for Split bet:" << endl;
    short answer;
    vector<short>* Selection = new vector<short>;
    for (short i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        cin >> answer;
        Selection->push_back(answer);
    }

    cout << "Enter how many chips and chip worth:" << endl;
    short chips, worth;
    cin >> chips >> worth;

    Bet* MyBet = new Bet(TableLayout::European, BetName::Split, chips, worth, Selection);

    Bet* Complex = new Bet(TableLayout::European, BetName::VoisinsDeZero, 1, 1);

    Complex->PrintProperties();

    cin.ignore(); // THIS IS IGNORED!!! WHY??? please...

    delete Selection;
    Selection = nullptr;
    delete Complex;
    delete MyBet;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I press F5 to run a program and then type in the numbers as follows:

1 enter
2 enter
1 enter
1 enter

and here cmd goes away, program skips cin.get() ( or cin.ignore() ) whatever it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you thinking of `cin.get()`?

Comment: No, I always use cin.ignore() to stop cmd window and it sometimes work and sometimes don't. according to <iostream> class documentation cin.ignore() must stop the window all the time not only sometimes isn'it? this is crazy man... what can I do?

Comment: Hey, even if I use cin.get() there is no difference LOL cmd disapears. now tell my that isn't crazy..

Comment: Please show what you typed into the console.

Comment: @Jesse, Hi I've edited my topic abowe to answer your request.

Comment: @codekiddy: The behavior of `cin.ignore()` is perfectly well defined, there is nothing "crazy" about it.  The problem is that you don't understand it or what your other code is doing (not trying to be mean, just a fact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cin >> chips >> worth;

On this line, for example, if you type the last `1` and press enter, A `\n` is still left in the stream unread.

When you do `cin.ignore();`, it extracts the leftover character and the program finishes. Change `cin.ignore();` to `cin.ignore(2);` and it should work.